# systemd fails to umount local partition... because of NFS

Tags: systemd

I have a setup, where the `/home` directory is mounted using NFS. This works without problems, all workstations are turning off properly. Recently I added a local partition (local HDD) to `/etc/fstab`, `XFS`, `defaults`, nothing fancy.

And now again `systemd` is `running a stop job for` umounting this **local XFS** filesystem. And cannot, beacuse it `cannot contact NFS server`. What NFS has to do with a local HDD? Could someone help?

The only way I managed to shorten the shutdown time is to set `x-systemd.device-timeout=5s,x-systemd.mount-timeout=5s`, but this is rather a hack, not a solution. I get `[FAILED]` during system shutdown after 5 seconds, this is not a graceful proper shutdown.

```
10.1.0.3:/home  /home   nfs some_options,sec=krb5    0   0
# Test local TMPFS
LABEL=TMPFS     /tmp_local  xfs     defaults,x-systemd.device-timeout=5s,x-systemd.mount-timeout=5s   0  0
```

Info:
Debian Buster
`systemd` version: 241